# trying to use ngClass instead ngIf

Tags: css, angular, ng-class

I would rewrite this NgIf over ngClass for a shorter code. Unfortunately, the class is not accepted. Can the problem be solved?

```
The long Version:   

 <div *ngIf="sp.outboundWeeks[i].status=='GREEN'">
                                        <div class="green">
                                            {{sp.outboundWeeks[i].utilizationRate}}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div *ngIf="sp.outboundWeeks[i].status=='RED'">
                                        <div class="red">
                                            {{sp.outboundWeeks[i].utilizationRate}}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div *ngIf="sp.outboundWeeks[i].status=='YELLOW'">
                                        <div class="yellow">
                                            {{sp.outboundWeeks[i].utilizationRate}}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

the short version should be like the code below:

[ngClass]="{'green':cw.status[i]=='GREEN','yellow':cw.status=='YELLOW','red':cw.status=='RED'}">{{cw.utilizationRate}}
     </div>
```

Comment: I think it should work. There is a `{` missing => `[ngClass]="{`

Comment: Hi Günter, thx for the hint, i made the change but unfortunately it still does not work

Comment: First it's `sp.outboundWeeks[i].status`, after that it's `cw.status[i]=='GREEN'` Can you post how you get `cw`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
<div>
   <div [ngClass]="(sp.outboundWeeks[i].status=='GREEN') ? 'green' : 
         (sp.outboundWeeks[i].status=='RED') ? 'red' : 'yellow'">
      {{sp.outboundWeeks[i].utilizationRate}}
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Abdul Rafay solutions is nice, my solution is in my opinion more explicit and readable :)

```
<div>
   <div [class.green]=" sp.outboundWeeks[i].status=='GREEN' "
        [class.red]=" sp.outboundWeeks[i].status=='RED' "
        [class.yellow]=" sp.outboundWeeks[i].status=='YELLOW' ">
      {{sp.outboundWeeks[i].utilizationRate}}
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume your objects are like:

```
    sp = {
    outboundWeeks: [{
      status: 'GREEN',
      utilizationRate: 'das',
    }],
  };
  cw = {
    status: ['GREEN'],
    utilizationRate: 'sad',
  };
```

therefore the template should be similar to

```
<div *ngIf="sp.outboundWeeks[0].status =='GREEN'">
      <div class="green">
        {{ sp.outboundWeeks[0].utilizationRate }}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="sp.outboundWeeks[0].status=='RED'">
      <div class="red">
        {{ sp.outboundWeeks[0].utilizationRate }}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="sp.outboundWeeks[0].status=='YELLOW'">
      <div class="yellow">
        {{ sp.outboundWeeks[0].utilizationRate }}
      </div>
    </div>

    //SHORT HAND
    <div [ngClass]="{'green': cw.status[0] === 'GREEN', 'yellow': cw.status[0] === 'YELLOW','red': cw.status[0] === 'RED'}">
      {{ cw.utilizationRate }}
    </div>
```

I guess your iteration is not correct coz the short version is a bit different from the longer version that you have introduced, however, I have added a sample object to show you how it should work.

A better solution might be to just create a `@Pipe` which returns your proper class. it should be much cleaner and faster.

something like

```
 <div [ngClass]="status | yourPipe">
      {{ cw.utilizationRate }}
 </div>
```

Comment: you are right Majid. I am an absolute beginner with Angular 4 and am happy about every little success ;)

Comment: keep working and you'll be an Angular master within the next couple of months :D, don't worry.